# Como enviar email con codeigniter 4.0.3

Tags: php, email, smtp, codeigniter-4

Necesito enviar correos electrónicos en mi sistema, sin embargo he probado todo lo que dice la guía de Codeigniter en su sitio web y no me permite enviar emails.

He realizado un `var_dump` a la variable `$email` y me arroja "Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method", sin embargo tengo otros sistema con codeigniter 3 y funcionan muy bien. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con codeigniter 4.0.3?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
    public function main() {
        $email = \Config\Services::email();

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['SMTPHost'] = 'Aqui va mi servidor';
        $config['SMTPUser'] = 'Aqui va mi usuario';
        $config['SMTPPass'] = 'Aqui va mi contraseña';
        $config['SMTPPort'] = 465;
        $config['SMTPCrypto'] = 'ssl';
        $config['mailType'] = 'html';
        $config['wordWrap'] = true;
        $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';

        $email->initialize($config);
        $email->setFrom('Correo del sistema', 'Sistemas');
        $email->setTo('Mi correo');

        $email->setSubject('Email Test');
        $email->setMessage('Testing the email class.');

        $email->send();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo y he usado varios SMTP y obtengo lo siguiente Incapaz de enviar email usando PHP SMTP. Su servidor puede no estar configurado para enviar correos usando este método.

Answer (score 2):

usa puerto 587, y si no tienes un certificado ssl utiliza tls o deja en blanco este campo

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer], para que tu respuesta no sea considerada de baja calidad.

Comment: Interesante. Había utilizado el 25, pero nunca el 587. ¿Es ese puerto uno de los puertos "por defecto" para SMTP?

Comment: No es el puerto de SSL, generalmente el puerto 25 es bloqueado por proveedores de internet para evitar spam